# Merge of two datasets with multiple conditions - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'd like to merge two .csv datasets with multiple conditions and I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Dataset1 ('movdf') has the counts of pedestrians and cyclists in 15min intervals for 2016 (1,2 mil rows). The other has the coordinates for the counting devices (there are 69 devices) ('locdf').

Hence, there is a problem with 'just' using the merge function based on their serialNr, because the devices are reinstalled at different locations throughout the year.

**Example:**

I'd like to get the right location (lng & lat) for every observation in movdf.

movdf:

[image: movdf]

locdf:

[image: locdf]

Counting device 'U15G3104442' is at location X until April 2016, then at location Y until October etc.).

Essentially the function has to take into condsideration both the date ('Installed') and the 'SerialNr' and then assign the correct Lng/Lat combination.

Is there a way to merge the two datasets in the following way:

- Assign location X (Cassioeiasteg) for all dates before April 1st 2016.
- Assign locatoin Y (Katzenbach) for all dates before October 1st 2016.
- Assign location Z (Zehntenhausplatz) for all dates after October 1st 2016.

The code would have to work for all the counting devices, not just one (U15G3104442).

Sorry if the question is basic and thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are not worried about memory abuse, you could simply merge according to SerialNr (that creates about 1.2 * 5 = 6M rows) `df = pd.merge(movdf, locdf.sort_values('Installed'))`, then select only the rows such that Date >= Installed `df = df[df.Date >= df.Installed]`, and finally use `df.groupby('SerialNr').last()`. This is quite a waste of memory and I have not tried it, so I'll just leave it here as a comment...

Comment: thanks for the comment! it works in the sense that it attributes the right location for each counting device at a certain time. but unfortunately it is too memory intense to perform efficient analysis on the dataset afterwards. I was thinking if i could do the merge with a `for` loop? or would that be even more memory demanding?

Comment: Rule of thumb should be that for loop is slower but less memory intensive. If you want to use it (reasonable if locdf is short) you don't need pd.merge at all: you can just do `movdf['Location'] = ''; for i in range(len(locdf)): movdf.loc[np.logical_and(movdf.SerialNr == locdf.SerialNr.iloc[i], movdf.Date >= locdf.Installed.iloc[i]), 'Location'] = locdf.Address.iloc[i]`. Here I assumed that you did `import numpy as np` and that locdf is sorted by installed, so that always at each loop it overwrites the previous installation.

Comment: sorry for the late answer and thanks a lot, it worked!